# voltdb-client-nodeJS doesn't work about @AdHoc proceduer

Tags: node.js, client, voltdb

I followed the [voltdb-client-nodeJS](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-nodejs), and implement the **@AdHoc** query function, but the "read" function didn't callbacked, so that can't get any queried results, can't determine if the connection is successful, too.

**[callProcedure code]**

```
var query = resultsProc.getQuery();
query.setParameters(["select * from Q_SHIPPINGCARRIERHISTORY_STREAMING where TrackingNumber=431476575751"]);
client.call(query, function read(errorCode, eventCode, results){
 ...
}, function write(errorCode, eventCode, results){
 ...
});
```

**[connect DB code]**

```
 var config = new VoltConfiguration();
 config.host = "s7biapp26";
 config.port = 8080;
 var client = new VoltClient([config]);
 client.connect(function(code, event, results){
    ...
 });
```

On the second attempt, can't `require('voltjs')` or `require('volt')` after `npm install voltjs`(version:voltjs@0.2.0).

So, could you provide a more detailed documentation about the **voltdb-client-nodeJS**, or paste a simpler demo of **@AdHoc**, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is connected voltdb failed by error code in connect callback function, I tried to remove the port, then connected success!

The secondly, requiring the module should `require('voltjs/lib/client')`.

referenced the links:

https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-nodejs/issues/12

https://forum.voltdb.com/forum/voltdb-discussions/building-voltdb-applications/577-nodejs-client-for-helloworld